# Undefined control sequence,amsfonts

Tags: fonts, errors

During compilation of my document I get the following error:

```
.............
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/misc/amsfonts.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \font\twtymsx=msxm10   \@magscale
                                  4
?
```

How to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (minimum working example) that generates the error messages you're encountering. Information about the TeX distribution and operating system you use would also be useful.

Comment: You seem to be using either some very old packages or a very old template. The font `msxm10` has been declared obsolete several years ago.

Comment: @egreg -- where "several" >> 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/misc/amsfonts.sty
```

You should be including

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
```

You have a spurious local file

```
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/misc/amsfonts.sty
```

that you should probably delete (and then re-run texhash)